# Thumbnail did not show in SIMOGEO Filemanager when deployed to Server, but it shown in Localhost

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, file-manager

[Thumbnail did not show in server, but can be shown in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkqVi.jpg)

[Image can use / attached to ckeditor, whether in server or localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya9md.jpg)

I'm new with codeigniter.
As can you see in the screenshot (2 links above), In the project I use CKEditor for text editor and SIMOGEO File Manager.

When I run it in the Localhost, there is no problem shown, but when deployed to server, the thumbails of images did not show, but that file image can be used / attached to the CkEditor, whether in localhost or server side.

When I press F12 in Google Chrome Browser, show the message like this :

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check ....

And when clicked, that error is :

```
if (f.open(a.type, a.url, a.async, a.username, a.password),
```

I've tried to find the solution to the problem through stackoverflow and other web community, but i did'nt get the solution for this problem.

I very hope the advice from all of you, master... :)

Thanks before...

Answer (score 0):

It just can be a permission issue ... be sure the server user has enough permissions to write on thumbnails folder.

By the way, you can test to call directly the thmunbail in your browser. The url would be similar to :

```
http://YOURSERVER.com/connectors/php/filemanager.php?mode=preview&path=%2Fuserfiles%2avatar.png&1455358031&thumbnail=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your respon mr.Simo :)
But it's still did not worked.

I had changed the permission of some folders to be 7 7 7, there are  :
[public_html/assets] - [public_html/assets/filemanager] -[public_html/assets/filemanager/userfiles] -
[.../filemanager/connector] -
[.../filemanager/connector/php]

(as you can see in this screenshot : www.bit.ly/1QyqVdr )

but it's still did not show the thumbnails.
And then, I had tried to call directly the thumbnail in my browser, unfortunately : "404 Page Not Found"

(as you can see in this screenshot : www.bit.ly/1RyMteM )

Hmm..
any advice, mr.Simo ? :(

Comment: Click on the "network" tab to see if it really returns a 404 error - seems to be. You can also check your server log to see what's happening exactly !

Comment: Also check if "_thumbs" folder exists under "your/path/FM/userfiles/"

Comment: when I press F12, Google Chrome give notification  : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" - 
`(http://)MYSITE.com/connectors/php/filemanager.php?mode=preview&path=%2Fassets%2Ffilemanager%2Fuserfiles%2FAvatar.png&1455364329&thumbnail=true`

Comment: STrange, indeed. May you share an online url for helping you? My mail is available into the code source : https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/blob/master/connectors/php/filemanager.class.php (i'm simon)

Comment: Please check your email, master.. :)